# Gradle build failing to find jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-8

I have a spring boot(2.1.9) gradle project which is trying to build by downloading a jar file from the artifactory but it is telling it is not able to find the jar file in the following location. But when I click on the link given `https://artifactory.build.ge.com/ARJLY/com/ge/digital/oa/common/oa-common/3.0.0/oa-common-3.0.0.jar` I am able to download the jar file. Why gradle is not able to download while building..anything I am doing wrong...
gradle version 6.8

My Artifactory path:

```
ARJLY
 com/ge
  digital/oa
   common
     oa-common
      3.0.0
       oa-common-3.0.0.jar
```

My build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        credentials {
            username "${artifactory_user}"
            password "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation('com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'io.micrometer', module: 'micrometer-core'
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors')
```

Error in gradle build

```
$ gradle clean build
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find oa-common-3.0.0.jar (com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://artifactory.build.ge.com/ARJLY/com/ge/digital/oa/common/oa-common/3.0.0/oa-common-3.0.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```